# string.replace(/""\n/g,"\"\""+ "\n") will this work?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
string.replace(/""\n/g,"\"\""+ "\n")
```

I am trying to parse a string and for using JSON parser. I need to replace the occurrence `""\n` (quote, quote, newline) with `\\"\\"\n` (slash, quote, slash, quote, newline).

I tried to do this by using escape sequence, but am not able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the single quote (`'`) string form to avoid escaping double-quotes unnecessarily this:

```
string.replace(/""\n/g, '\\"\\"\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression /\"\"[\n|\r]/g

`str.replace( /\"\"[\n|\r]/g, '\\"\\"\r' );`

It works for me :)